# Deleting temp files automatically

Tags: asp.net

I'm facing a problem of deleting temp files because i have changed the Version of the build
and now when I'm debugging the same Proj errors was coming due to old version temp files can anybody help me on deleting temp files automatically with some time log or deleting at some period whatever the solution may be...?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a tempolary file with FileOptions.DeleteOnClose